# C# - Formatting .txt Document Problem

Tags: c#, list, format, text-files, spacing

Here is the text file that I am loading in:

***ORIGINAL FILE***

```
10 BARE PCB
20 T C40
B C5, C45, C48
30 B C25
40 B C17, C18
50 B C15
60 T C20, C23,
B C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12,
C31, C32, C33, C34, C35, C36,
C37, C38, C39
70 T C16, C21, C22, C24, C41, C42
B C3, C19, C43, C44, C47
80 T C13, C14
B C1, C2
90 B C26, C27, C28, C29, C30
100 T R65
110 T R35
120 T R34
130 T R33
140 T R21, R22, R29, R30
150 B R28, R31, R32, R37
160 T R17, R19, R26, R47, R50, R51,
R53, R57, R58, R59
B R18, R25, R42, R48, R49, R52,
R54, R55, R56, R60
170 T R23
B R10, R43
180 T R8, R9
190 T R13, R14, R15, R61, R62, R63,
R64
200 T R27, R38, R39, R40, R41
B R2, R3, R11, R44, R45, R46
210 B R1
220 T C4
230 T D1
240 T U1
250 B U10
270 B U6
280 B U5
290 B U4
300 T U2
310 B U7
320 B U8
330 T U9
340 B L2, L3
350 B L8, L9
360 B L1, L4, L5, L6, L7, L10
370 B J1, J2
380 B J3
390 B X1
400 T X2
410 B J4
420 B J5
422 B U3
2000 T TRACKING LABEL
423 ADHESIVE
424 ACCELERATOR
425 ADHESIVE
```

---

And this is what I have the file being formatted to:

***FORMATTED FILE***

```
0010 BARE PCB
0020 C40
0020A C5, C45, C48
0030A C25
0040A C17, C18
0050A C15
0060 C20, C23,
0060A C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12,C31, C32, C33, C34, C35, C36,C37, C38, C39
0070 C16, C21, C22, C24, C41, C42
0070A C3, C19, C43, C44, C47
0080 C13, C14
0080A C1, C2
0090A C26, C27, C28, C29, C30
0100 R65
0110 R35
0120 R34
0130 R33
0140 R21, R22, R29, R30
0150A R28, R31, R32, R37
0160 R17, R19, R26, R47, R50, R51,R53, R57, R58, R59
0160A R18, R25, R42, R48, R49, R52,R54, R55, R56, R60
0170 R23
0170A R10, R43
0180 R8, R9
0190 R13, R14, R15, R61, R62, R63,R64
0200 R27, R38, R39, R40, R41
0200A R2, R3, R11, R44, R45, R46
0210A R1
0220 C4
0230 D1
0240 U1
0250A U10
0270A U6
0280A U5
0290A U4
0300 U2
0310A U7
0320A U8
0330 U9
0340A L2, L3
0350A L8, L9
0360A L1, L4, L5, L6, L7, L10
0370A J1, J2
0380A J3
0390A X1
0400 X2
0410A J4
0420A J5
0422A U3
2000 TRACKING LABEL
0423 ADHESIVE
0424 ACCELERATOR
0425 ADHESIVE
```

---

***HOWEVER***

If you look closely in the formatted file there is a few spots where there is no space after one of the commas (C12,C31 & C36,C37 & R51,R53 & R52,R54 & R63,R64). I would like there to be a space in between there..

***CODE***

```
    private void openRefsFormatHelper()
    {
        try
        {
            // Resets the formatted refs text.
            formattedRefsTextRichTextBox.ResetText();

            // Reads the lines in the file to format.
            var reader = File.OpenText(openRefs.FileName);

            // Creates a list for the lines to be stored in.
            var list = new List<string>();

            // Adds each line in the file to the list.
            while (true)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                list.Add(line);
            }

            // Handles all of the requirements for the reference text.
            list = fourDigitRequirement(list);
            list = concatRequirement(list);
            list = startsWithBRequirement(list);
            list = elementIsBRequirement(list);
            list = removeTRequirement(list);

            // Prints the formatted refs to the richtextbox.
            foreach (var line in list)
                formattedRefsTextRichTextBox.AppendText(line + "\n");
        }

        // Catches an exception if the file could not be formatted.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was a problem formatting the 'Refs File'.", "Refs File Format Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

    static List<string> elementIsBRequirement(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();

        // Checks each line in the list.
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // Splits each line into 'parts'
            var parts = line.Split(' ');

            // Checks if the second 'part' array is "B"
            if (parts[1].Equals("B"))
            {
                // If it is "B", replace with "A" and add to the new list "result"
                parts[0] += "A";
                parts[1] = string.Empty;

                result.Add(string.Join(" ", parts));
            }

            // Otherwise keep the line how it is.
            else
                result.Add(line);
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }

    static List<string> startsWithBRequirement(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();
        var i = 0;

        // Checks if the line begins with "B"
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // Splits each line into 'parts'
            var parts = line.Split(' ');

            // Checks if the first 'part' array is "B"
            if (parts[0].Equals("B"))
            {
                // If it is "B", copy the previous line down and add "A" where "B" was at
                // and add to the new list "result".
                parts[0] = string.Empty;
                result.Add(list[i - 1].Split(' ')[0] + "A" + string.Join(" ", parts));
            }

            // Otherwise keep the line how it is.
            else
                result.Add(line);

            i++;
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }

    static List<string> concatRequirement(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();

        // Checks each line in the list.
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // Splits each line into 'parts'
            var parts = line.Split(' ');
            int test;

            // Concats everything together
            if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out test) || parts[0].Equals("B"))
                result.Add(line);

            // Otherwise result - 1
            else
                result[result.Count - 1] += line;
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }

    static List<string> removeTRequirement(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();

        // Checks each line in the list.
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // Splits each line into 'parts'
            var parts = line.Split(' ');

            // Checks if the second 'part' array is "T", if it is, remove "T"
            if (parts[1].Equals("T"))
                parts[1] = string.Empty;

            // Add the new string to the result.
            result.Add(string.Join(" ", parts).Replace("  ", " "));
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }

    static List<string> fourDigitRequirement(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();

        // Checks each line in the list.
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // Splits each line into 'parts'
            var parts = line.Split(' ');
            int test;

            // Checks if the array[0] (digits) is the proper length.
            if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out test))
            {
                // If it is not a length of 4 digits, add "O" to the front until it is.
                parts[0] = parts[0].PadLeft(4, '0');

                // Add the new string to the result list.
                result.Add(string.Join(" ", parts));
            }

            // Otherwise keep the line how it is.
            else
                result.Add(line);
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }
```

---

***QUESTION:***
 - How do I get that space in there?

Comment: Can you narrow your code down a bit? We can't review your whole application for you.

Comment: Also, you should totally drop what you have and try LINQ. :-)

Comment: @dtb - Well all of the **static List<string> functions** are just formatting the file how it is suppose to be. The problem I have has to do with the **newline** character not being properly formatted to a space... or something like that? Do you still need me to narrow the code down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In concatRequirement, you can change:

```
            result[result.Count - 1] += line;
```

to

```
            result[result.Count - 1] += " " + line;
```

Answer (score 2):

Without desk-checking the whole thing, I notice that the problem entries are where the value is at the end of the line.

Try appending a space to the line before you split it. Maybe.

Comment: I just realized that too. I will check to see that that does the trick

Comment: Yes that worked! Now I have to deal with a different issue though.. :-/

Comment: Unless I am splitting it in a wrong spot....? I split it in the very first **while loop** by replacing **list.Add(line);** with **list.Add(line + " ");**... is there a better place to split it?